# Embed VueJs Frontend into Django Backend

Tags: django, vue.js

I have a vue Js frontend and a Django backend running on 2 different ports. Currently I want to embed the frontend into the backend and both only output to a single port.

I tried embedding the frontend and backend and both only output 1 port on the backend to run, but essentially still run 2 ports.